# Distribution for first time to have drawn all colors

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Consider an urn with $n=\sum_{i=1}^rn_i$ balls, where $n_i$ represents the number of balls of color $i$ (out of $r$ possible colors).

What’s the distribution describing the first time it takes to have drawn all colors, with replacement? For example, with red, blue, and green balls and a draw sequence of: blue, blue, blue, red, red, blue, green, the time is seven. Is this a known (parametric) distribution?

Comment: Let $X_1=1$. Take $X_2=1$ if the second ball you pick has a different color than the first one and $X_2=0$ otherwise. Now take $X_3=1$ if the third ball you pick has a different color than the first two and $X_3=0$ otherwise, etc. Put $$S_m=X_1+ \dots + X_m$$ If $n_1=\dots =n_r$ then $\{S_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is a Markov chain on the state space $\{1, \dots , r\}$ with transition probabilities $$P(S_{m+1}=i|S_{m}=i)=\frac{i}{r}$$ $$P(S_{m+1}=i+1|S_{m}=i)=\frac{r-i}{r}$$

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476506/probability-distribution-of-coupon-collectors-problem-in-the-general-case-of-un

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is an instance of what is known as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) where you have $\ r\ $ "coupons" with probabilites $\ \frac{n_1}{n},\frac{n_2}{n},\dots,\frac{n_r}{n} \ $ of being received on each draw.  The "classical" version of the problem, on which there's an enormous literature, is to calculate the *expected number* of draws needed to obtain a collection containing a given number of distinct coupons when the probabilities of each coupon being received on each draw are all equal.  You'll find a solution to this problem on pp.210-211 of volume $1$, $2$nd edition, of Feller's
[*An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*](https://archive.org/details/introductiontopr00fell/page/n7/mode/2up).  The solution of the same problem for the case when the probabilities are *not* equal can be found in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27595975?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

There appears to have been much less written about the *distribution* of the waiting time to obtain a complete collection, and on trawling briefly through pages returned by a google search, I  didn't come across any where this was derived.  I give a formula for it below.

Let $\ B_{it}\ $ be the number of balls of type $\ i\ $ in the collection after $\ t\ $ draws. Then $\ \big(B_{1t},B_{2t},\dots,B_{rt}\big)\ $ is [multinomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution):
$$
P\big(B_{it}=b_i\ \text{for}\ 1\le i\le r\big)=\frac{t!}{b_1!\,b_2!\  \dots\,b_r!}\prod_{i=1}^r\Big(\frac{n_i}{n}\Big)^{b_i}
$$
if $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^rb_i=t\ $.

Let $\ T\ $ be be the draw on which the collection is completed. Then $\ T=t\ $ if and only if $\ B_{i\,t-1}\ge1\ $ for all $\ i\ $ *except exactly one*, say $\ i=j\ $, $\ B_{j\,t-1}=0\ $, and a ball of type j is received on draw $\ t\ $. Thus, if $\ t\ge r\ $, then
\begin{align}
P(T=t)&=\sum_{j=1}^rP\big(B_{j\,t-1}=0, B_{i\,t-1}\ge1\ \text{for}\ i\ne j, 1\le i\le r\big)\Big(\frac{n_j}{n}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{n_j}{n}\sum_{\hspace{0.7em}b_j=0\\b_i\ge1,i\ne j\\
\sum_ib_i=t-1}\frac{(t-1)!}{b_1!\,b_2!\  \dots\,b_r!}\prod_{i=1}^r\Big(\frac{n_i}{n}\Big)^{b_i}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^r\sum_{\hspace{0.7em}b_j=1\\ b_i\ge1,i\ne j\\
\sum_ib_i=t}\frac{(t-1)!}{b_1!\,b_2!\  \dots\,b_r!}\prod_{i=1}^r\Big(\frac{n_i}{n}\Big)^{b_i}\\
&=\frac{1}{t}\sum_{j=1}^r\sum_{\hspace{0.7em}b_j=1\\ b_i\ge1,i\ne j\\
\sum_ib_i=t}\frac{t!}{b_1!\,b_2!\  \dots\,b_r!}\prod_{i=1}^r\Big(\frac{n_i}{n}\Big)^{b_i}\\
&=\frac{1}{t}\sum_{j=1}^rP\big(B_{jt}=1,B_{it}\ge1\ \text{for}\ i\ne j, 1\le i\le r\big)\ .
\end{align}
The $\ j^{\,\text{th}}\ $ summand in the sum on the right side of the final identity is the probability that exactly one of the first $\ t\ $ balls drawn is of the $\ j^{\,\text{th}}\ $ type, and at least one ball of every other type appears in those first $\ t\ $.  The last identity thus confirms the plausible hypothesis that this probability should be $\ t\ $ times the probability that a single occurrence of a ball of the $\ j^{\,\text{th}}\ $ type during the first $\ t\ $ draws occurs on the $\ t^{\,\text{th}}\ $ draw, and at least one ball of every other type appears during those draws.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a compact nice result is available. For large $r$ (nombre of colours) the following Poisson approximation could be useful:

Letting $p_i = n_i/n$ and $X_1, X_2 ... X_r$ be the amount of extracted balls of each color, after $t$ extractions, we can approximate the multinomial distribution by a set of independent Poisson variables with $\lambda_i = p_i t$

In this approximation, letting $T$ be the number of extractions needed we get

$$P(T> t)  = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^r(1-e^{-p_i t})$$
and

$$P(T= t)  = P(T>t-1) - P(T>t)= \prod_{i=1}^r(1-e^{-p_i t})-\prod_{i=1}^r(1-e^{-p_i (t-1)})$$